# How I can subscribe to one queue by multiple consumers using MassTransit?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm using Azure Service Bus as transport for MassTransit and I'm trying to send message(command) to queue:

```
var sendEndpoint = await busControl.GetSendEndpoint(sericeUri);
sendEndpoint.Send<ISimpleRequest>(new SimpleRequest(customerId));
```

Also I try to connect to this queue by two consumers:

```
var _busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
            {
                var host =  cfg.Host("...", h =>
                {
                    h.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                });
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "queueName",
                    e => { e.Consumer<RequestConsumer>(); });
                cfg.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();
            });
```

The same code with same queue name for second consumer.
After I send message only one consumer get the response. So how I can config this to work with two or more consumers?

Comment: you are better off using topic and subscriptions for this. post one message in a topic and multiple subscribers can subscribe to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get two copies of the message, one for each consumer, you should use two separate queues and `Publish` the message. In this case, MassTransit will send it to the topic, and each queue will receive a copy forwarded from the topic.